# Tethering app code for iOS

Tags: iphone, tethering

Many of you know there was a Flashlight app with a hidden feature that enabled tethering, that snuck into the App Store this week. It was removed very quickly, about 10 minutes before I found out so I wasn't able to snag it up. I have a developer account so I was thinking if I could get the code to a tethering app I could install it on my phone myself.

Are there any open source tethering apps out there?

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer myself.

http://wiki.github.com/tcurdt/iProxy/

w00t!